# Integrating Gulp with Django manage.py

Tags: javascript, python, django, gulp

Does Django's `manage.py` have hooks?

I'd like to run some gulp tasks and I want it to be seamless for the rest of the team.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these hooks are called [Custom Management Commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/).  You can easily create custom `manage.py` command and call `gulp` from it via python's built-in `os`  or `subprocess` modules.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented some custom management commands to do this for `runserver` and `collectstatic`: [django-gulp on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-gulp)